# Edge loop realignment?

Tags: loop, modeling

How do I realign these edge loops to evenly align around the bend?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try "Smooth vertices" (Right click in vertex select mode).

[image: Smooth1]

You can increase the number of "smooth" steps from the operator panel. Be careful, though, you could end up changing the overall shape of your mesh slightly.

[image: Smooth2]